# Disable post of one form element of a form that posts

Tags: javascript, html, forms

This is my code:

```
        <form action="/login" method="POST">
            <label for="username">Username: </label><input type="text" name="username" id="username">
            <label for="password">Password: </label><input type="password" name="password" id="password">
            <label for="enc_key">Encryption Key: </label><input type="password" name="enc_key" id="enc_key">
            <input type="hidden" name="next_page" value="{{ next_page }}">
            <input type="submit" value="submit" id="login_submit">
        </form>
```

Basically I want the username and password to post, but I do not want the enc_key to post. The enc_key is handled by javascript. Is there a way to do this without moving the enc_key input field outside of the form tags?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try removing the name attribute.
You will still be able to handle your enc_key with the ID, but the input without a name won't be posted.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest thing to do would be to clear that field right before the form posts:

```
document.getElementById("enc_key").value = '';
```

Comment: this is a good strategy, but i really do not want to post anything at all.